# Problem while copying JTable contents into Excel

Tags: java, excel, jtable

I have a Standalone application in which I am trying to copy contents of `JTable` into Excel with line breaks included in my cells of `JTable`. I have used wrapping using `"\""` to my cell contents. It's working fine but I am getting a square box type of symbol in place of line breaks in Excel. How to remove the symbol while copying? Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Excel expects DOS/Windows line breaks (`"\r\n"`) instead of Unix/Java ones (just `"\n"`). To fix this, use this code:

```
s = s.replace("\r\n", "\n").replace("\n", "\r\n");
```

The first part makes sure that you don't have any DOS/Win line breaks and then converts everything to DOS.

If you're stuck with Java 1.4, use `replaceAll()`.

[EDIT] The square box means that there is an unprintable character in the string. I suggest to create a file with Excel which contains a line break in a cell and check which characters Excel uses.

Comment: thank you for your reply..i tried by replacing using s.replace("\r\n", "\n").replace("\n", "\r\n"); 

but the boxes are still appearing in the excel.
here is my code:

S = (String) "\""+mProcessQuestionTestItemTable.getValueAt(rowsselected[i], colsselected[j])+"\"";
S=S.replace("\r\n", "\n").replace("\n", "\r\n");
stringbuffered.append(S);

Comment: I had written code for pasting contents of Excel to Jtable
I tried as you said, i traced the contents of the excel,but i dint find any special character or symbol other than the "\n".
In Excel,to go for the next line in cell,we need to press Alt+Enter.
Do we need to catch that alt+Event and replace the \n's in jtable with these Alt+Enter events.If copy that squarebox and paste in another cell,alt+enter event is happening i.e a new line within in the cell.

Can anyone help me out?
Thank you

Comment: No; try to create a file where every bit is the same as what Excel produces. In this case, remove the second `replace()` to make sure you only have `\n` in the output.

Comment: I have created an excel file with line breaks(using Alt+Enter) in each and every cell and pasted it in a notepad file.I got the boxes now in notepad.when i copy the same(copied from excel) content from notepad to excel with boxes. Now the boxes are not visible in excel.can you suggest me how to get the value of this box and replace \n with it?i have tried alot but i cant find the solution.Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: any suggestions to remove the empty square box from excel(cloipboard) which is appearing before the line break in excel while pasting the JTable contents to Excel.

Comment: Load the file in an editor which can show you the hex values of each character. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors

Comment: Don't use "Cut&Paste" (Ctrl-C/V) because that allows the programs to "fix" the string. You need to know the byte values so use files.